# Get values after going through type decorators for orm events in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to make an audit trail for my database with orm events, currently catching the data in the after_update, insert, delete events. Then recording it in the after_commit.

This is working great for the most part. I am getting the values of the records with their **dict** method. The only problem with this is that it gives me the values before the bind_processor in my type decorator.

So my question is this. Is it possible to get the values of a orm record object with the bind_processor applied?

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to figure out a solution, I feel like there must be an easier way to get the data after the bind_processor, but this gets the job done.

I added this method to my sub-classed Base class.

```
def bind_processed_dict(self):
    """Returns a dictionary of all column values after going through their bind processor"""
    value_dict = self.__dict__
    ret_dict = {}
    for col_name, col in self.__table__.columns.items():
        bindprocessor = col.type.bind_processor(dialect=engine.dialect)

        val = value_dict[col_name]
        if bindprocessor is not None:
            val = bindprocessor(val)

        ret_dict[col_name] = val

    return ret_dict
```